# Network connection service

Tags: android, sqlite, networking

I have this android application that does certain stuff that need online connection, but if the phone isn't connected to internet the entries I want to send to the online database are kept in a sqlite table.
My question is how can I resend these entries once the phone connects to internet, what topics should I search for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use BroadcastReceiver to monitor the internet state of you phone.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mobile = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        NetworkInfo wifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo active = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(active == null) { //no internet

        }
        if(mobile.isConnected()) { //mobile connetcion

        }
        if(wifi.isConnected()) { //wifi connetcion

        }
}
```

}

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

<application

...

<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
```